# PowerBI I need to calculate the datediff

Tags: powerbi-desktop

in PowerBI I need to calculate the datediff between the date on the row to the maximum date possible on the table

Example

```
Table A ( this table has no id for each row)
Row . Date
1 .      1-jan-2000
2.      7-jan-2000
3.      8-jan-2000
4.      10-jan-2000
5.      31-jan-2000
```

What I am trying to get

```
Row . Date .              Maximum Date in Table        Calculated Column DateDiff (days)
1 .      1-jan-2000 .     31-jan-2000                             30
2.      7-jan-2000 .      31-jan-2000                             24
3.      8-jan-2000 .     31-jan-2000                             23
4.      10-jan-2000 .    31-jan-2000                             21
5.      31-jan-2000 .   31-jan-2000                              0
```

I have tried to create a measure of the max date, and used last date, but when looking at the row it just gives the date as the current date of the row and not its max date of the table

every row should have the same maximum date, and i can then calculate the diff between the date on the row and the max date

Answer (score 0):

I started with data given below -

[image: Given Data]

Step 1:- 
*Make Sure your Date Column in the Table belongs to data type "Date".*

Step 2:- 
*Create a **calculated column** using DAX then, with the DateDiff function*

```
Date Diff = DATEDIFF(MyTable[Date],MAX(MyTable[Date]),DAY)
```

Here is a link to learn the [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datediff-function-dax) function.

The output looks like below :-

[image: Output]

Kindly accept the answer if it works for you or let me know if it doesn't.